# How to distribute data between threads in OpenMP?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

Let's say that I have an array of a certain size n and I also have n threads. Now I would like to give one element of the array to each of the threads at the beginning of the program. How would I do this in OpenMP?

Comment: It would be easier to give a good answer If you tell us more of what you like to achieve. What is an element? How are elements created? Will you be actively modifying an element? Otherwise it's easy to fall into traps like false-sharing by manual worksharing that has better idiomatic solutions.

Comment: This doesn't scale too well. If we have 100,000 array elements, we can't have 100,000 threads. So, we have `n` elements and `t` threads. Generally, when `t` is greater than (e.g.) 8, the memory bus becomes swamped and increasing the number of threads is of diminishing return. And, with a large number of threads, we spend more time switching between threads vs getting actual work done. And, I second Zulan's comment about editing your question and explaining more about what you're trying to achieve as this affects the type of answer that would be best for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use omp_get_thread_num() within a parallel block to get the thread ID, and then use that ID to index into your shared array of length n. Make sure to make any variable you use to hold the thread ID private/local.

Comment: This looks like a sure way to produce false sharing, if the array indexed that way is updated.  The normal and preferred way is to give each thread (in effect) a sequential array section.  In some situations, this data partitioning may remain the same throughout the program, even with multiple parallel regions.